# Can my computer handle this graphic card?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, vga

I have a motherboard MSI MS-7309 VER: 2.2 K9N6PGM2-V2 Socket AM2. I have looked at the motherboard specifications and there is VGA max shared memory 256mb.

I want to buy a graphic card with 1gb. Will this GPU be compatible with my motherboard?

Answer (score 0):

"VGA Shared Max" is for **onboard**, or **integrated graphics processing**, it has nothing to do with a dedicated, or discrete graphics card.

As per the specifications on your vendor's website, it has a PCI-Ex Gen1 (1x16) slot, which can be used for a graphics card. Gen2, and Gen3 graphics cards will operate when placed into the slot, but at reduced performance.

Another area to consider is your Power Supply, or PSU. Ensure that when you pick a dedicated graphics card, that your PSU has enough wattage and amperage to support it.

Web Links:

https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/K9N6PGM2V2.html#hero-specification

Answer (score -1):

The VGA max shared memory is for onboard graphics, so you should be good, although I would recommend you upgrading the rest of your system as it's clearly very old, also what graphics card do you want and what power supply do you have? The graphics card might need more power than can be provided, also this motherboard is a micro ATX so you might have a micro ATX case meaning you will want to check to see if your GPU can fit in a small case